# Prove that $f$ is invertible

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Did I show enough to prove $f$ is invertible? Alternatively is there a more efficient way to do so? Thanks in advance for any help.

> Let $f : X \rightarrow Y $a nd $g : Y \rightarrow X$ be functions.
>
> Assume $g\circ f$ is injective and
>   $f\circ g$ is surjective.
>
> Prove that $f$ is invertible

i)First assume $a, b \in X$ and $f(a) = f(b)$.

Then $(g \circ f)(a) = g(f(a)) = g(f(b)) =(g \circ f)(b)$.

However, $g \circ f$ is injective. Therefore $a = b$.

ii)Next assume $a \in X$. Since $f \circ g$ is surjective.

Then there is $b\in Y$ such that $(f \circ g)(b) = a$.

Set $c = g(b)$. Then $f(c) = f(g(b)) = a$ and $a \in Range(f)$.

Since $a$ is arbitrary it follows that $Range(f) = X$.

Thus since $f$ is both injective and surjective it is bijective and equivalently invertible.

Comment: This seems right to me! A quick remark, you have actually proved that if $f\circ g$ is injective then $g$ is injective and if $f\circ g$ is surjective then $f$ is injective.

Comment: Yup, you're good.

Comment: Should not be $a,b\in Y$?

Comment: As far as I know, to prove a function for being invertible, it is enough to show it for being injective. There is no need for demonstrating $f$ to be  surjective.

Comment: And in the fifth line of prove, I think you may replace $a, b\in X$ with $b\in Y$ to make the proof without typos.